# fatal exception asynctask #1 doinbackground

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

I am having this issue in calling a dotnet webservice.

This is my doinbackground

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Log.w("myApp", "in async");
        //Call Web Method
        loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(editTextUsername,editTextPassword,"Login");

        //Log.w("myApp", String.valueOf(loginStatus));
        return null;
    }
```

This is my locat.

```
 07-08 03:29:32.467: W/dalvikvm(1341): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ab5ba8)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): Process: com.prgguru.example, PID: 1341
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.prgguru.example.WebService.invokeLoginWS(WebService.java:79)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.prgguru.example.CheckDNLoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:72)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.prgguru.example.CheckDNLoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(CheckDNLoginActivity.java:1)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     ... 4 more
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: here you go `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 03:29:32.497: E/AndroidRuntime(1341):     at com.prgguru.example.WebService.invokeLoginWS(WebService.java:79)`

Comment: Did you initialize `WebService`?

Comment: @Aniruddha well just the relevant part should be fine eh?

Comment: I referred to this tutorial. Exactly the same code, just the web-service changed to mine. http://android.programmerguru.com/android-dot-net-web-service-login/

Comment: What exactly did you change? Only URL?

Comment: Thanks for the support. I fixed the issue. I am totally new to Java and Android. I worked on Web-services (Dotnet) for which I had to create a POC for our android developers. Thanks again.